# Getting redirected URL in Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, url, redirect, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to GET some web pages for some crawled URLs. Many of those URLs actually redirect to different URLs (e.g. because they have been processed with a URL shortener). Additionally to downloading the content, I would like to resolve the final URLs (i.e. the URL which provided the downloaded content), or even better, all URLs in the redirect chain.

I have been looking through the API docs, but got no clue, where I could hook. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a full demo](https://gist.github.com/paxan/5588336) of how to do it using Apache HttpComponents.

### Important Details

You'll need to extend `DefaultRedirectStrategy` like so:

```
class SpyStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {
    public final Deque<URI> history = new LinkedList<>();

    public SpyStrategy(URI uri) {
        history.push(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(
            HttpRequest request,
            HttpResponse response,
            HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        HttpUriRequest redirect = super.getRedirect(request, response, context);
        history.push(redirect.getURI());
        return redirect;
    }
}
```

`expand` method sends a HEAD request which causes `client` to collect URIs in `spy.history` deque as it follows redirects automatically:

```
public static Deque<URI> expand(String uri) {
    try {
        HttpHead head = new HttpHead(uri);
        SpyStrategy spy = new SpyStrategy(head.getURI());
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.setRedirectStrategy(spy);
        // FIXME: the following completely ignores HTTP errors:
        client.execute(head);
        return spy.history;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You may want to set maximum number of redirects followed to something reasonable (instead of the default of 100) like so:

```
        BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setIntParameter(ClientPNames.MAX_REDIRECTS, 5);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

Comment: Wow, it's been a while, but during a long needed refactoring after an HttpComponents update I integrated your solution and it works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to turn off automatic redirect handling by setting the [relevant parameter](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1169), and do it yourself by checking for 3xx responses, and manually extracting the redirect location from the responses "Location" header.

Comment: Thank you, did it like suggested by you. Works!