# how to add RedirectStrategy to Apache HttpComponents NHttpReverseProxy

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I want to enable redirection in the HttpComponents [NHttpReverseProxy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpReverseProxy.java) example.  To me, it seems the logical place would be to implement a [Http Protocol Processor](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e228), but I haven't found one that I can implement or extend.  I have seen the stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176538/906048) that discusses a parameter that handles automatic redirect handling, but that link is broken.  I also looked at an [example on github](https://gist.github.com/paxan/5588336), but I'm not sure how to incorporate that code into the Reverse Proxy example.

Answer (score 0):

`NHttpReverseProxy` represents an extremely basic implementation of a reverse proxy with all non-essential bits omitted mainly intended to demonstrate efficient handling of inbound and outbound message streams using an event-driven non-blocking i/o model. For more complex scenarios one could use [Apache HttpAsyncClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/index.html) to execute outbound requests, which would automatically handle redirects